# How to implement a book preview (2 page spread) without using Flash?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, vml

I'm looking into a solution for work, where you have a two page spread of the book to preview. Either side of this, you can hover in the corner to create a pseudo-flip and then click the mouse button to actually turn the page. I know there is many Flash solutions out there, but in this case we cannot use it... So we are looking for a possible solution that can work across all major browsers (yes, including IE6)...

I looked a few canvas solutions, but with Google's canvas extension for IE, these will terribly slow. So was thinking about an SVG/VML solution, like Raphael Javascript library. This could be good, but then trying to look into how to code this, without examples, could be a challenge with the time constraint.

Is there a solution out there that fits (or almost fits) this problem?

Comment: You actually want the animation of a page folding and turning?

Comment: BTW, Google's (Erik's) canvas extension for IE is SVG/VML solution, just like Raphael Javascript library!

Comment: Can you give a link to a Flash-based solution demo?

Comment: "(yes, including IE6)" - makes it unlikely that you'll find a solution unless it's allowed to gracefully degrade into something relatively static for IE6

Comment: Thanks for replies. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a solution... Will have to just stick with Flash :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the [SVG Flip](http://www.paulbrunt.co.uk/2009/11/07/svg-flip-blog-post/) solution by Paul Brunt? It seems to do exactly what you ask for, using svg and javascript.

Comment: This is almost very great! ...I got excited to see the demo, tried it on IE and was happy to see it working there... But then realised I was looking at an example Flash on he links too - not the actual SVG example. I tried the SVG FLip on IE 6 + 7 and it just doesn't work... Thank you, but still looking...

Comment: Thanks for the link. There seems to be no real answer to this. But thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few demos for different browser generations:

- [Book flip via CSS3 transforms](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay36.html)
- [Book flip via CSS2.1 absolute positioning](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/book.html)
- [Book flip via DHTML](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/bookflip.htm)